# How to upload Audio file to wordpress via Rest API from flutter

Tags: wordpress, flutter, api, audio, wordpress-rest-api

I am able to upload images via API to WordPress but not audio files, it gives HTTP 500 error when I try to pass the Audio file to the method. But when I pass the image it uploads successfully,
here is the function.

I'm using the `Dio` package.

```dart
Future<bool> UploadFileToWordpress(File file) async {

    try {
      final token = MyConstant.token;

      String apiURL = "https://prostate-wrench.000webhostapp.com";
      String uri = "$apiURL/wp-json/wp/v2/media";

      String fileName = file.path
          .split('/')
          .last;
      print(fileName);

      FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
        "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
          file.path,
          filename: fileName,
        ),
      });

      Dio dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ${MyConstant.token}'
          },
          contentType: "application/json")
      );
      var response = await dio.post(uri, data: data);
      print(response.statusMessage);
      if (response.statusCode == 201) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }

   
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.. added ".mp3" extension with filename variable and its perfect now

Comment: The answer require clarification on the solution that you have applied. Add an example code which explains how it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
        "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
          file.path,
          filename: fileName,
          contentType: ...,//need to add this part 
        ),
      });
```

import 'package:mime/mime.dart';   //don't forget import

```
var lookUpMime =lookupMimeType(file.path);
```

now need to split type

```
      var mimeString = mimeType.split('/')[0];
      var mimeType = mimeType.split('/')[1];
```

and add it as contentType:

```
contentType: MediaType(mimeString, mimeType),
```

I think it helps